# Call scrollsToTop programmatically in scrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

So I know you can disable/enable the `scrollsToTop` gesture (i.e. tap status bar) with `view.scrollView.scrollsToTop = true`

But is it possible to call this gesture programmatically?

Comment: Just set the content offset to 0,0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get UIScrollView to scroll to the top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450302/get-uiscrollview-to-scroll-to-the-top)

Comment: A content offset of `0,0` isn't always the desired scroll position. `UICollectionView`'s with non-default content insets, for example.