# UITextView initial scroll position is not top on tvOS

Tags: uitextview, tvos

How to make the initial scroll position be 0 on **tvOS**? I tried `setContentOffset:CGPointZero` and `layoutIfNeeded`, but it's not working.

```
[self.textView layoutIfNeeded];
self.textView.attributedText = myLongAttributedString;
[self.textView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
[self.textView layoutIfNeeded];
```

This is similar but different from [UITextView initial scroll position is not 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602155/uitextview-initial-scroll-position-is-not-0) because my given solution for iOS isn't working for **tvOS**.

You can quickly reproduce the issue from tvOS example from https://github.com/laptobbe/TSMarkdownParser/tree/3.x (commit [fba04cdd59ac55fc324a2100fcb800af2153f2af](https://github.com/laptobbe/TSMarkdownParser/commit/fba04cdd59ac55fc324a2100fcb800af2153f2af) in case I fix the bug in the future) and switching the selected output to UITextView (with keyboard arrow if you're on simulator):
[image: tvOS screenshot]